# Why is the function $y(x) = (x^2, 2x + 1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ not onto?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

[image]

To ascertain injectivity, I simplify $\alpha(x_1) = \alpha(x_2)$.  Then equate the components:

$\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}
x_1^2 & = x_2^2 \\
2x_1 + 1 & = 2x_2 + 1
\end{cases}   
\Longrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x_1 & = \pm x_2 \\
x_1 & = x_2
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow  x_1 = x_2 \neq -x_2. $ Thus $\alpha$ is $1-1.$

The question of surjectivity is:  for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R \times R}, $ does there exist $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha(r) = (x, y)$? I then try to find such an $r$ by solving $\alpha(r) = (x, y)$ for $r$ wrt $x, y$:

$\alpha(r) = (x, y)
\implies (r^2, 2r+1) = (x, y)
\implies  \begin{cases}
r^2 & = x \\
2r + 1 & = y
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
r &= \pm \sqrt{x}  \qquad (*)\\
r & = \frac{y - 1}{2} \qquad (**)
\end{cases}$.

$1.$ What can and should I infer from this? I calculated $r$ so doesn't this imply that $\alpha$ is onto?

**Supplementary to Michael Albanese's Answer:**

$2.$ What/where in my work betrays its failure for $x < 0$? Thanks to the feedback, I now realise this. Still, I don't perceive this in my work above and want to do so.

Comment: $x^2$ is always non-negative.

Comment: Find an $r$ that yields, say, $x=-1$.

Comment: Is there an $r\in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\alpha(r) = (-1,-1)\in \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$?  Clearly not, since $r^2\neq -1$ so $f$ can't be surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the reason your working fails to show that $\alpha$ is surjective is that it is no longer valid if $x < 0$ (which corresponds to the fact that the image of $\alpha$ is a subset of $[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$).

You can answer questions like this relatively quickly by looking at the component functions. For example, let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$. Then:

- if $f_i$ is injective for some $i$, then $f$ is injective, and
- if $f_i$ is not surjective for some $i$, then $f$ is not surjective.

Note that these are only sufficient conditions, they are not necessary. For example, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x) = (x^2, x^2 - 1)$ is injective, but the component functions are not, while $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x) = (x, -x)$ is not surjective, but both of the component functions are.

**Added later:** Just to clarify, you have shown that $\alpha$ is injective, but you have failed to show that $\alpha$ is surjective (because $\alpha$ is not surjective).

Let $\alpha_1(r) = r^2$ and $\alpha_2(r) = 2r+1$.

1. You have shown that if $r = \pm\sqrt{x}$, then $\alpha_1(r) = x$, and if $r = \frac{1}{2}(y-1)$, then $\alpha_2(r) = y$. To show that $\alpha$ is surjective, we need to find $r$ such that $\alpha(r) = (\alpha_1(r), \alpha_2(r)) = (x, y)$. That is, we need to find $r$ such that $\alpha_1(r) = x$ **and** $\alpha_2(r) = y$. This is only possible if $\frac{1}{2}(y-1) = \sqrt{x}$ or $\frac{1}{2}(y-1) = -\sqrt{x}$, which is not true in general. If you are still not convinced, try to find $r$ such that $\alpha(r) = (1, 1)$.
2. The place where you use $x \geq 0$ is when you write $r = \pm\sqrt{x}$. If $x < 0$, $r \not\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1. Thank you. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions? Also, how is $f(x) = (x^2, x^2 - 1)$ injective? $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1^2 = x_2^2 \implies x_1 = \pm x_2 $. Will you please to respond in your answer.

Comment: The function $f(x) = (x^2, x^2 - 1)$ is not surjective. You've shown that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $x_1 = \pm x_2$; you have not shown that if $x_1 = \pm x_2$ then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ (you still need to consider the second component function). As far as I am aware, there are no necessary conditions that you can impose on the component functions to make the overall function injective/surjective.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm bewildered. Since you wrote in your answer that $f(x) = (x^2, x^2 - 1)$ is injective, I was trying to prove this. Nonetheless, you mention surjective in your previous comment? Which did you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I meant that $f(x) = (x^2, x^2 - 1)$ is injective, despite the fact that the two component functions are not injective.

Comment: Thank you. No problem. I'm still bewildered. $\Large{{ 1.1}}$ Didn't I show $\alpha(x_1) = \alpha(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ ? I did conclude $x_1 \neq x_2 $. $\Large{{1.2}}$ Also, why do I need to prove $x_1 = \pm x_2 \implies \alpha(x_1) = \alpha(x_2)$?

Comment: Lastly, I'd be grateful if you could please respond to my supplementary in my OP. Will you please to do so in your answer and not as a comment?

Comment: I will answer your question soon, and will do so by adding to my answer.

Comment: I thank you profoundly for your benevolent devotion to my questions. Before accepting, I want to verify that I apprehended your answer so I added some details to it. Could you please check if they represent what you meant? Please pardon any errors and feel free to rollback/edit it. Sorry for not knowing how to realign the numbers.

Comment: I have rolled back (and fix up a typo from the previous version of my answer). Note, that $\alpha(r) = (x, y)$ only if $\frac{1}{2}(y-1) = \sqrt{x}$ **or** $\frac{1}{2}(y-1) = - \sqrt{x}$. You changed the 'or' to an 'and'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been flummoxed by the "impossible" so erroneously changed the "or."

Answer (score 1):

It's all in this line of yours:

$\alpha(r) = (x, y)
\implies (r^2, 2r+1) = (x, y)
\implies  \begin{cases}
r^2 & = x \\
2r + 1 & = y
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
r &= \pm \sqrt{x}  \qquad (*)\\
r & = \frac{y - 1}{2} \qquad (**)
\end{cases}$.

At the last step you didn't draw the helpful conclusions. Given $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ the equation $2r+1=y$ enforces $r={y-1\over 2}$, and then $r^2=x$ enforces $$x={(y-1)^2\over4}\ .\tag{1}$$
If $x$, $y$ together don't satisfy $(1)$ then there is no $r\in{\mathbb R}$ with $\alpha(r)=(x,y)$. It's easy to produce such a point $(x,y)$, e.g., $(x,y):=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I unclock the details for this part of Michael Albanese's answer above:

> If you are still not convinced, try to find $r$ such that $\alpha(r) = (1, \color{#009900}{1})$.

Substitute $x = 1$ into $(*). \implies r = \pm 1$.
Substitute $\color{#009900}{y = 1}$ into $(**). \implies r = 0$.
Thus $r = 0 = \pm 1$, a contradiction!.